May readdir() cause OOM?
I tried to iterate through a directory in Linux system. The program is run on a chip, so OS memory is limited in 25MB. The directory only contains images, each with size about 3MB. What program does is read each image in the file and do some process. But program failed when reading about the 4000th image, and I am not able to find out the reason.
first try with scandir()
I used scandir() function, the code looks like this.
void MyFunc(const std::string &fileDir)
{
    struct dirent **entry_list;
    int32_t count = scandir(fileDir.c_str(), &entry_list, nullptr, alphasort);
    if (count == -1) {
        printf("open dir:%s failed.\n", fileDir.c_str());
        return;
    }

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        struct dirent *ptr = entry_list[i];
        if (strcmp(ptr->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ptr->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // read image
        // do process
        // release image
    }
}

This code worked fine until I met a large directory with 30,000+ images in it. So I thought scandir() will go through the entire directory and cause the program collapse.
second try with readdir()
With previous experience, I tried readdir() this time.
void MyFunc(const std::string &fileDir)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(fileDir.c_str());
    if (dir == nullptr) {
        printf("open dir:%s failed.\n", fileDir.c_str());
        return;
    }
    ScopeGuard dirGuard([&] { (void)closedir(dir); }); //RAII

    struct dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != nullptr) {
        if (strcmp(ptr->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ptr->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // read image, the same scandir verison
        // do process, the same scandir verison
        // release image, the same scandir verison
    }
}

Surprisingly, this time the program will report OOM error when reading approximately the 4000th image, while scandir() version fails when directory has about 10,000+ images in it.
So what may cause the collapse of readdir version? Is entry acquired one by one?
------------------ Second Edition: ----------------
I did closedir() in the code. The code is remedied.
------------------ Third Edition: ----------------
third try
My third attempt looks like this:
void MyFunc(const std::string &fileDir)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(fileDir.c_str());
    if (dir == nullptr) {
        printf("open dir:%s failed.\n", fileDir.c_str());
        return;
    }
    ScopeGuard dirGuard([&] { (void)closedir(dir); }); //RAII

    std::vector<std::string> tmp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != nullptr) {
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        tmp.emplace_back(fileDir + "/" + entry->d_name);
    }
    printf("process img total %zu.\n", tmp.size());

    for (const auto& fileName: tmp) {
        // read image, the same scandir verison
        // do process, the same scandir verison
        // release image, the same scandir verison
    }
}

Strangely enough, this code performs perfectly fine with a directory of 10,000+ images. No more OOM and collapse. Now I am more confused.

This is expect behavior because you don't call closedir().

Does the OOM happen even when you comment out all of the code that does the image reading, processing, etc?  If not, my suspicion would be that there is a memory leak somewhere in the image-handling code, rather than in readdir() or scandir().

Can you use C++'s filesystem?

Currently, we are sticking with C++14, so answer is no. @PepijnKramer

I am quite sure my reading and processing has no memory leak in there. Please see my third try. @JeremyFriesner

Does your target embedded-system have any kind of memory-profiler you can use to see what's going on? If not, if you run your program on a desktop with a profiler attached do you see any obvious problems?

Disable memory overcommit, set errno=0 before readdir() and check it after readdir() return NULL. You can also add memory consumption monitoring into the program if no external tools available.

Your second try (without processing code) run with glibc 2.40 allocates the same amount of memory for reading directory with 100 files and with 1000000 files, according to valgrind.
